# Override Virtual Function thats already Overriden

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am attempting to override/overload a virtual function that has already been overridden in a base class. To better understand what I want to do please look at the following example:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual void foo() {
        print("Parent::foo()");
    }
}

public class Derived : Parent
{
    public override void foo() {
        print("Derived::foo()");
    }
}

public class Child : Derived
{
    public override void foo() {
        print("Child::foo()");
    }
}


// When I create an instance of Child and call the method foo, 
// it calls the Derived::foo() method and not Child::foo()
// How can I make Child override Derived::foo()?
```

Is it possible to override Derived::foo()? If not how would you suggest I solve this problem?

Comment: This works perfectly on ideone [link](http://ideone.com/AKFCZT).

Comment: What's the code you're using to call it? This should work.

Answer (score 2):

This calls `Child::foo` in C#.  Try this code:

```
class Program {
    static void Main()
    {
        Parent foo = new Child();
        foo.foo();
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Parent
{
    public virtual void foo() {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent::foo()");
    }
}

public class Derived : Parent
{
    public override void foo() {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived::foo()");
    }
}

public class Child : Derived
{
    public override void foo() {
        Console.WriteLine("Child::foo()");
    }
}
```

This will run and print `Child::foo()`.

Comment: @ja72 It's really not, other than it'll actually compile and run.  It does demonstrate, with working code, that this conceptually works properly.  (The OP's code uses "print" which won't compile...)

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure without seeing your calling code, but are you sure you didn't make a mistake and create an instance of `Derived`?